# Rails Routing Redirects to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

I have a view called, "clients" which shows a list of calls from the Call database.  That works fine.  However when I added a new button with a form behind it the call will be created but it redirects to calls_path instead of clients_path.

I have no idea why it's doing this, my only theory is that I'm working with actions that touch data outside of the clients_controller and somehow Rails is defaulting to the calls_path.  The same thing happens on my delete action.  Can someone help me make sense of this?

```
calls_controller
def new
    @call = Call.new :call_status => "open"

    respond_with @call
  end

  def create
    @call = Call.new(params[:call])

     if @call.save
        redirect_to clients_path, notice: "Call was successfully created."
      else
        render :new
     end
  end 

  def destroy
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
      @call.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to clients_index_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :caller_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :caller_name %>
  <%= f.label :caller_phone %>
  <%= f.text_field :caller_phone, :placeholder => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' %>
  <%= f.label :caller_email %>
  <%= f.text_field :caller_email %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>

routes.rb
devise_for :users
  match 'mdt' => 'mdt#index'
  get "home/index"
  resources :medics
  resources :clients
  resources :users
  resources :units
  resources :mdt do
    collection do
      put "in_service"
      put "en_route"
      put "to_hospital"
      put "at_hospital"
      put "on_scene" 
      put "out_of_service" 
      put "at_station"
      put "staging"
      put "at_post"
      put "man_down"
  end
  end
  resources :calls do
    member do
      post 'close'
    end
  end
  root :to => 'home#index'
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was with routes.  I needed a post method for a new calls.  After creating two actions (one for create and one for destroy) along with their routes everything started working.  It looks like it was trying to use the default routes and actions which would re-route to the wrong URL for my purposes.

```
resources :clients do
    collection do
      post "calls"
    end
    member do
      delete "cancel"
    end
  end



 def calls
    @call = Call.new(params[:call])

     if @call.save
        redirect_to clients_path, notice: "Call was successfully created."
      else
        render :new
     end
  end 

  def cancel
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
      @call.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to clients_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
```